# lecture for Quality Inspectors - how to write on CV

Tags: word-usage

I need to write a CV in English, however, I have a problem how to express an idea that I was giving lectures for quality inspectors and that I was giving lectures about a specific subject.

Right now I have it like this:

> 2000-present self-employed
>
> - lecture for Quality Inspectors
> - lecture in the field of „IT systems in medicine”

Is it correct? Or perhaps should I use:
-performing lectures for Quality Inspectors
-conducting lectures in the field of "IT systems in medicine”

Or maybe both options are not appropriate, and you could propose me some better solution.

Comment: What's wrong with saying what you said above -- Self-employed as a lecturer on the topic of IT systems in medicine, instructing quality inspectors?

Answer (score 0):

```
-Quality control inspector trainer
-Lecturer in the field of IT systems in medicine
```

No quotation marks are needed, especially not German-styled quotation marks.

I think that the term "quality control" and so "quality control officer" or "quality control inspector" is more used. You didn't simply lecture them, you trained them. If you are a college professor, then you can re-orient your cv to include that fact and the subjects you taught, among them, "quality control."

Also, self-employed unfortunately has negative connotations. Why not say, "independent contractor"?